# protobuf-net deserialized list's item's are uninitialized

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Is there any known issue or common mistake which would result in a list being deserialized with the correct number of items but for all of those items to be uninitialized? Note: The item type is marked with ProtoContract and has several ProtoMember(s).

My types....

```
[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(LoadBoardAction))]
public abstract class GameBoardAction : IGameBoardAction
{
}

[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
public class LoadBoardAction : GameBoardAction
{
    [ProtoMember(10)]
    private List<GameTileState> _tiles;
}

[ProtoContract]
public struct GameTileState
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Point Coordinate;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public TileType Type;
}
```

Serialization...

```
// Note: action is a LoadBoardAction with 15 elements in _tiles
var stream = new MemoryStream();
Serializer.Serialize(stream, action);
var buffer = stream.ToArray();
stream.Close();
// buffer gets sent across network here...
```

Deserialization...

```
// stream is a MemoryStream initialized to the byte[] which has 
// be read from a network packet.
var action = Serializer.Deserialize<GameBoardAction>(stream);
```

Action will have 15 elements in _tiles but `GameTileState.Coordinate` is always `(0,0)` and `GameTypeState.Type` is always `TileType.Null`.

Edit:

The enum TileType is actually serialized/deserialized correctly, the issue is Point, which is an XNA struct type and hence its public fields X/Y are not marked for serialization in any way. This is definitely the issue. I just assumed that it knew to read/write the public fields of a struct when that struct was marked as a ProtoMember of a known type.

While I wish this worked automatically it looks like the work around is to add something like this (for all XNA math types)...

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Point), false).Add("X", "Y")
```

Edit:

Verified that adding the above mentioned line fixes the issue.

Comment: Nothing leaps to mind; can we see your class?

Comment: I just realized something, Point is not a ProtoContact type (nor can it be, its not my type) I just assumed it would work because it is a struct and hence writing/reading all public fields would be logical.

Comment: Also, TileType is not a ProtoContract type, I just assumed it would work because it is an enum.

Comment: enums should work by default. Structs often work because they tend to have representative constructors that match the layout.

Comment: GameTileState does not have an explicit constructor defined, in my case.

Comment: I just stepped through the whole write process. When it get down to an individual GameTileState value, then goes to write the Coordinate field, the serializers list is empty, so it writes nothing (without complaining either). Point is a struct with two public fields X and Y which I was expecting to be written at this point.

Comment: I verified that the enum is being written/read. It is only the Point that is not.